# update column of table 1 according to the similar column of table 2, Sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two tables in sqlite. Let's say table_1 and table_2. table_1 has two columns named(Barcode, Price) , similarly table_2 has two columns named(Barcodes, Price). I want to update table_1.Price. if table_1.Barcode is present in table_2. Barcodes, then take the price of table_2. Price otherwise keep it table_1.Price.
I hope I am very clear. Let me just write it down in a programmatic sense to be very clear.

```
if(table_1.Barcode == table_2.Barcodes)
    table_1.Price = table_2.Price
else
    table_1.Price = table_1.Price
```

I need sqlite query which does this. Is it possible?

Comment: Please read the info on the tag you used https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info and provide a MRE as described there of your database. Also please focus your question on the sqlite part, also as described. You can later ask another question on how to implement the SQLite query in C++. Please add the desired result for the sample data in your MRE. (I have removed the tags which are not apparently relevant in your question, to get you started on focusing the question.) Generally please take the [tour] and read [ask] to find out about the concepts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you can do it with `UPDATE...FROM` syntax:

```
UPDATE table_1 AS t1
SET Price = t2.Price
FROM table_2 t2
WHERE t2.Barcode = t1.Barcode;
```

For older versions of SQLite you need a corelated subquery which returns the price from `table_2`:

```
UPDATE table_1
SET Price = COALESCE(
              (SELECT t2.Price FROM table_2 t2 WHERE t2.Barcode = table_1.Barcode),
              Price
            );
```